# GAE: File uploading failing on live

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've created a brand new project on Google App Engine using the 1.8.2 SDK.

I'm trying to build a file uploader, locally the file uploader works fine, after deploying it and attempting an upload, I'm getting the following error:

```
POST http://test2.website.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6bj08dli8J-kL3D_xdt…cQ6YCoQx3NC1s4If-C2J1moqV7Lg/ALBNUaYAAAAAUhExcSNKV9D3-0TadzZaCtssmKinnP5T/ 
503 (Service Unavailable) _ah/upload/AMmfu6bj08dli8J-kL3D_xdthBPw4H3jir2X86RQ3dQPlV5LukvcH9t7OP8dK147…6YCoQx3NC1s4If-C2J1moqV7Lg/ALBNUaYAAAAAUhExcSNKV9D3-0TadzZaCtssmKinnP5T/:1
```

I've enabled billing on both GAE and Google Cloud Storage.

The code I'm using to generate the upload url is as follow:

```
public static String getUploadUrl(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bucket = "website-uploads";
        BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
        UploadOptions uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName(bucket);
        return blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload", uploadOptions);
    }
```

I'm using normal servlets to handle the multipart post:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (!SH.isLoggedIn(req)){
            SH.redirectPage(req, res, 200, "/login");
            return;
        }

        BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
        Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
        List<BlobKey> keys = blobs.get("file");     

        if (keys != null && keys.size() > 0) {
            BlobKey blobKey = keys.get(0);
            SH.setAttribute(req, "blobKey", blobKey.getKeyString());
        } else {
            SH.setAttribute(req, "uploadError", "An error occurred while uploading ...");
        }

        SH.setAttribute(req, "uploadUrl", getUploadUrl(req));
        SH.gotoPage(req, res, 200, JSP.pageUpload);
    }
```

And then my form doind the submit:

```
<form id='uploadForm' action="${uploadUrl}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input id="imageUploader" name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Looking at the on/off panel, it appears that cloud storage is enabled:
[image]

Is there anything wrong with my code or is this something Google needs to fix?

Update:

Based on Lipis' comment, I've added the needed permissions:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't give permission from the Google Cloud Storage for your application.

From the docs use the step [number 5](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/), skip the deprecation part if you are not actually using that, I just didn't find the instructions anywhere else.

Comment: I've added the "CAN EDIT" permission in the cloud storage console, but it says "Invitation sent. Waiting for response." Do I need to approve it somewhere or does it happen automatically?

Comment: I tried adding it again, works the second time, thanks for the pointer :-)